# Unsatisfiable constraints when installing packages on docker alpine

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm build a docker image based on `ruby:2.3-alpine`. I need to install couple of packages for my rails application to run normally. Unfortunately the following packages does not exists on alpine repositories.

What's the way to install them?

```
$ uname -a
Linux 50642453afd5 4.1.17-boot2docker #1 SMP Thu Feb 11 08:12:31 UTC 2016 x86_64 Linux
$ apk add iceweasel
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  iceweasel (missing):
    required by: world[iceweasel]
```

Packages to install:

- libav-tools
- xfonts-base
- xfonts-75dpi
- iceweasel

Comment: have a look at
https://hub.docker.com/r/plaperdr/blinkbrowsers/~/dockerfile/

and see how Chrome or Opera is installed, you see the idea

Comment: Do the same for libav-tools and others

Answer (score 4):

As of June, 2016 "firefox-esr" [replaces Iceweasel.](https://wiki.debian.org/Iceweasel%20%22replaces%20Iceweasel%22.)

Here's how to install it in an Alpine Docker container, and to run it to verify it's installed correctly:

```
FROM ruby:2.3-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache firefox-esr
RUN firefox --version
```

You'll probably also need a virtual display (framebuffer) like xvfb. See this for more info => https://github.com/rickypc/docker-python-firefox-xvfb/blob/master/Dockerfile